# Synchronizing two SQL Server Instances

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-replication, database-cluster

I have two network segments and both are connected using the internet, say one as corporate server and another as remote production. I have an Intranet application running in both environments using the single SQL instance, everything works fine. But my production environment internet disconnects frequently, so my application unable to reach corporate SQL Instance and production stops for a while. Now I'm thinking of placing a server in remote production, and I want to sync up(automatically) once the internet is connected. I'm new to this area please help me.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to sync database objects then you can use Replication.
Read more on MSDN at [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198(v=sql.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)